# Preprocessor constant evaluation

Tags: c, compilation, c-preprocessor

I have a small question about the preprocessor constants in C. I understand what is the goal of this kind of "variable" and how it works. However, I have a small question about their evaluation. Let's consider a small example :

```
#define MY_VARIABLE 5

int main() {
    int test1 = MY_VARIABLE*5;
    int test2 = 5;
    int test3 = MY_VARIABLE*test2;
}
```

During the preprocessor step, `MY_VARIABLE` will be replaced by 5 in the code. My question is: will `test1` be computed during the compilation or during the execution ? Is that correct that `test3` will be computed during the execution ? This question may seem a bit weird and useless but I'm studying a program where this kind of things is done a lot of times and I would like to know if this kind of operation can slow the execution.

Comment: test1)initial value is no evaluation at the time of execution. test3)initial value  will no evaluation at the time of execution by inference when outputting the code.

Comment: Let's says computation then :)

Comment: Actually your question isn't at all about _precprocessor constant evaluation_,

Comment: How about you give it try and see whats the result ;)

Comment: I'm not pretty sure I understand what you mean. Do you mean that the executable will not compute anything ? So test2 will be replaced in test3 and test3 will be computed ?

Comment: @user1382272 see my answer below.

Comment: Macros are not even "variables". As much as copy/paste in the editor is not. And they are also no constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already understood, the C preprocessor merely replaces the macros before the actual compilation takes place, therefore I stripped out all preprocessor related stuff.

In **this** code no evaluation takes place during execution because the compiler calculates 5*5 during compile time and by inference is can also evaluate all other constants during compilation:

```
int main() {
    int test1 = 5 * 5;
    int test2 = 5;
    int test3 = 5 * test2;
}
```

The exact equivalent of the preceeding code fragment is:

```
int main() {
    int test1 = 25;
    int test2 = 5;
    int test3 = 25;
}
```

But in following code `test3` is evaluated during run time, because the value of `test2` cannot be determined during compile time, because it depends on the return value of `SomeFunction` that can only be known at run time.

```
int main() {
    int test1 = 5 * 5;
    int test2 = SomeFunction();        
    int test3 = 5 * test2;
}
```

Comment: Note that the value for `test3` may also be computed during execution depending on the compiler's optimization settings. For debugging settings it's not unusual for the `test3` value to be computed during debugging.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I still have one : let's say that test3 = MY_VARIABLE + j; where j is a variable updated at each loop iteration. Will it also be computed during the compilation if the optimization is set ?

Comment: @atturri that may be true, for example if `SomeFunction` returns a constant.

Comment: @user1382272 of course `test3 = MY_VARIABLE + j` will be computed after each loop iteration at run time, because `j` is not constant. What else would you expect?

Comment: @user1382272 you understand that `test3 = MY_VARIABLE + j` is **strictly** the same as `test3 = 5 + j`.